# DolphinDB: Character count in a string

Tags: string, count, dolphindb

How to return the number of a specified character in a String, such as the number of comma in the following String:

"Aasd,LLLL,xxx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DolphinDB‘s function `regexCount` can meet your demands. You can try the script:

```
str = "Aasd,LLLL,xxx"
regexCount(str, ",")
```

Also, regexCount can return the number of all occurrences of a regular expression, see [regexCount — DolphinDB 2.0 documentation](https://www.dolphindb.cn/cn/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/r/regexCount.html) for its reference.

Alternatively, you can also use the function `split` to count the size of the vector output, like:

```
split(str, ",").size() - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regexCount("Aasd,LLLL,xxx", ",")
```